# PHP Captcha showing all field in URL

Tags: php, html

I'm using Captcha and php for registering data input.

When the form is submitted, the fields and all the data are displayed in the URL. The form is submitted successfully, but I need to hide the data from the URL.

This is my single line code that I am using submitting the form with captcha:

```
$.post("submit_demo_captcha.php?"+$("#register").serialize(), { }, function(response){

//checking response here
```

I know I have to take a variable and assigned it to the empty bracket but don't know how. Please help me..

Comment: Read the jquery documentation, in particular the page about `$.post`.

Comment: Thanks Charlotte. It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
$.post("submit_demo_captcha.php", {"rowdata":$("#register").serialize()}, function(response){
```

I hope this will help